# Twitter bootstrap collapsing but not showing properly in mobile view

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am designing a website but when I view it on mobile view the carousel doesn't show with 100% width and also the nav off sets a bit.

Heres a picture.

http://oi45.tinypic.com/30dbh91.jpg

My code is pretty much the base Bootstrap CSS and I can't figure how to fix the mobile view so it will show properly with `.collapse`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the carousel, but with the navbar, it's too wide.

I could not figure this out until I saw the website URL in the lower left corner. You really should have attached some relevant CSS to your question and maybe a link to the site. Providing an image as a reference is not enough in most cases.

Add this in your CSS: *(on line 45, which you left empty)*

```
.navbar-wrapper .navbar {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry,will do in next time, and thanks the carousel is now okay but the navbar is stil the same :/ doesn't fully show on mobile view.